# Android - Download a folder from server or anywhere from internet and apply changes according to it in app

Tags: android

I just finished one app, but i want to let user install different language packs (a folder containing mp3 files ), and also apply those mp3 files in my app ! how should i do it ?
how to let user user download that folder ?
and how to make changes in my app as they download ?

(this is like google maps app, they tell you which map you want to install and so on ! mine is related to mp3 files ! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot download folder. Folder is just a container, but all the data is held in files, not folders. So you have to download all files stored in folder or, which may be simplier, distribute your files in archive (like zip), then no matter how many files is needed, or what folder structure you need, all you have to do is download one file and unpack it.

Comment: ok. and any idea about how do i make changes in my app as some 1 download ?